# Working on cjuiautocomplete Showing Exception

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii

i tried the code from te source of

[Source Code i used for CJUIAutoComplete](http://www.yiiplayground.cubedwater.com/index.php?r=UiModule/jui/ziiAutocomplete)

not getting where the mistake is
error showing as not authorised please help me i am new to Yii framework and for Debugging also.

Here goes my Error Log

```
2012/05/25 06:07:28 [error] [exception.CHttpException.403] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'You are not authorized to perform this action.' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php:157 

Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php(120) CAccessControlFilter->accessDenied(Object(CWebUser), 'You are not aut...')
#1 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(39) CAccessControlFilter->preFilter(Object(CFilterChain))

#2 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(1146): CFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))
#3 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(59) CController->filterAccessControl(Object(CFilterChain))


#4 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(131) CInlineFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))

#5 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(292): CFilterChain->run()

#6 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)

#7 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276): CController->run('autocompleteTes...')

#8 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController('details/autocom...')

#9 C:\wamp\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()

#10 C:\wamp\www\myapp\index.php(13): CApplication->run()

#11 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/myapp/index.php?r=details/autocompleteTest&term=asss
HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost/myapp/index.php?r=details/create
```

**Controller Code is**

```
<?php
class DetailsController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/column2';

/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

    public function actionAutocompleteTest() {
$res =array();

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $qtxt ="SELECT name FROM {{details}} WHERE name LIKE :username";
    $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
    $command->bindValue(":name", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res =$command->queryColumn();
}

echo CJSON::encode($res);
Yii::app()->end();
}


/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Details;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Details']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Details'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id1));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Updates a particular model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Details']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Details'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id1));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Deletes a particular model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}

/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Details');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Details('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Details']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Details'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
 * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
 * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
 */
public function loadModel($id)
{
    $model=Details::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}



/**
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param CModel the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='details-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
}
```

**Form Code**

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'details-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>


        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'test1',
    'value'=>'test21',
    'source'=>$this->createUrl('details/autocompleteTest'),
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',
    ),
));
    ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'phone'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'phone'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'phone'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Thanks
Devendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this its very simple for you..

```
public function actionAutoCompleteLookup()
        {
           if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && isset($_GET['q']))
           {

              $name = $_GET['q']; 

               $qtxt ="SELECT name FROM details WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%'";
               $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);

               $userArray =$command->queryColumn();

              $returnVal = '';
              foreach($userArray as $userAccount)
              {
                 $returnVal .= $userAccount->getAttribute('first_name').'|'
                                             .$userAccount->getAttribute('user_id')."\n";
              }
              echo $returnVal;
           }
        }
```

And in the view code like this..

```
<?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete',
          array(
                         //name of the html field that will be generated
             'name'=>'name', 
                       //replace controller/action with real ids
             'url'=>array('detail/AutoCompleteLookup'), 
             'max'=>10, //specifies the max number of items to display

                         //specifies the number of chars that must be entered 
                         //before autocomplete initiates a lookup

             ));
    ?>
```

its work fine...

Comment: i copied as it is - showing this error in error log  2012/05/25 06:55:48 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "admin/AutoCompleteLookup".' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:280
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController('admin/AutoCompl...')
#1 C:\wamp\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 C:\wamp\www\myapp\index.php(13): CApplication->run()

Comment: #3 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/myapp/index.php?r=admin/AutoCompleteLookup&q=de&limit=10&timestamp=1337928948219
HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost/myapp/index.php?r=details/create

Comment: in view give give the wrong Url... correct the Url like 

     'url' =>array('Controller name/AutoCompleteLookup');

Comment: if i changed to (controlername/action) - showing not authorised

Comment: you wrote like this .. 'url' =>array(Details/AutoCompleteLookup),

Comment: i am using the Db Name - details  - controller Name is DetailsController.php  and added view code in _form.php file. me db table Attributes are id1, id, name, phone, email.

Comment: 2012/05/25 07:47:42 [error] [exception.CHttpException.403] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'You are not authorized to perform this action.' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php:157
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php(120): CAccessControlFilter->accessDenied(Object(CWebUser), 'You are not aut...')
#1 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(39): CAccessControlFilter->preFilter(Object(CFilterChain))
#2 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(1146): CFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))

Comment: #3 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(59): CController->filterAccessControl(Object(CFilterChain))
#4 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(131): CInlineFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))
#5 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(292): CFilterChain->run()
#6 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#7 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276): CController->run('AutoCompleteLoo...')

Comment: #8 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController('Details/AutoCom...')
#9 C:\wamp\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#10 C:\wamp\www\myapp\index.php(13): CApplication->run()
#11 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/myapp/index.php?r=Details/AutoCompleteLookup&q=de&limit=10&timestamp=1337932062468
HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost/myapp/index.php?r=details/create

Comment: Friend if u r free - please try to login to my sys once - i strucked here from 2 days

Comment: how can i login to your sys freind?

Comment: teamviewr - give me ur personal id or else my id is - devendar.gona at gmail.com

Comment: sorry freind.. i have checked my code..its properly running.. so i think you have a problem in your config file or some where else..

Comment: please login to my sys once or else can i send the total app code

Comment: is this ur id in fb : owais.iqbal.357

Comment: Thanks for your help dude - at last i got it

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your DetailController:

```
array('allow', 
      // allow authenticated user to perform 'create', 'update' and 'autocompleteTest' actions
      'actions'=>array('create','update', 'autocompleteTest'),
      'users'=>array('@'),
),
```

Comment: @Segey  Thanks for the reply - but still showing same error Log

Comment: i added the above code in DetailConstroller under actionAutocompleteTest() function - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code:

name is the attribute of model(Database table)

```
public function actionAutoCompleteLookup() {
    $res =array();

    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

        $qtxt ="SELECT name FROM customer WHERE name LIKE :name";
        $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
        $command->bindValue(":name", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $res =$command->queryColumn();
    }

    echo CJSON::encode($res);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

View Code

Create URL - Controller Name/ Actin(Function Name u written in Controller)

```
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'test2',
    'source'=>$this->createUrl('Customer/AutoCompleteLookup'),

             'options'=>array(
             'showAnim'=>'fold',
              ), 
));
    ?>
```

Thanks to Stackoverflow